# Clarifying understanding of handling of arguments in functions

Tags: go

For the sake of a simple example, suppose we use the code bellow to read the `body` of a http Get request:

```
func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://google.com")
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    bs := make([]byte, 99999)
    resp.Body.Read(bs)
    fmt.Println(string(bs))
}
```

As far as I know, In Go, variables are passed to functions by value (therefore functions work with a copy of the passed value and not the original value itself); and the [documentation of Go for `Read` method](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) is:

```
type Reader interface {
    Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

As per documentation, `p []byte` is of type `[]byte` and not a pointer of it (`[]*byte`); Then how is it that the `resp.Body.Read` method is accessing and editing the `bs` variable itself directly (which is not a pointer)?

Comment: `[]T` is a *slice*. Slices contain pointers to underlying *arrays*. What's copied here is the slice, a small piece of memory, efficient to be copied over and over. What's *not* copied is the underlying, pointed-to array.

Comment: This one's a great article on slices: https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

slice type define of reflect.SliceHeader

```golang
type SliceHeader struct {
    Data uintptr
    Len  int
    Cap  int
}
```

Although the slice is a value, the address of the value points to a pointer, so the slice can be treated as a ptr attribute before expansion.

The Reader interface modifies the []byte object just like the pointer modification. Finally, the Read method returns the length of the modified data, the length of `n <= len(p)`.

After the slice is triggered to expand by append, a new slice is created. The data address of the new slice is different from the expanded address.

In Go, channels, maps, and slices save a data address, so they can all show the nature of pointer references; however, the slice append method will return a new data pointer after expansion, and will show a similar value-passing property.

Comment: My English translation is too bad, thanks for the correction. @Peter

Answer (score 0):

In Line here:

```
bs := make([]byte, 99999)
```

When you are making a slice, you actually creating an Array and receiving a pointer to that array named bs(Slice). Now Go does that for you implicitly and it is a layer of abstraction.

Now, in the line

```
resp.Body.Read(bs)
```

you are actually passing a pointer for modification. resp.Body.Read(bs) does not yell at you because you are fooling Read() by saying "Hey Read(), bs is not a pointer, i promise. ;)"